# Отправка запросов на С++ сервер

Tags: c++, api, сокет, клиент-сервер

Стоит задача написания микросервиса который посылает запросы на готовый сервер написанный на С++. Сервер написан очень давно и с современными технологиями как я понял дружит не охотно. Информация которая у меня на "руках" это айпишник, порт. Подскажите куда капнуть надо чтобы сервер принял запросы и прислал ответ соответственно. Пытался отправлять тестовые запросы через постман, но все тщетно.
Не могу разобрать какие запросы посылать (post, get, put или же option) не отвечает ни на один из них. Стоит ли отправлять запросы прямо в файл типо http://localhost:1530/main.cpp или же архитектура C++ сервера подхватит автоматом. Знаю то что под капотом используются сокеты, а может и эта инфа без полезна.
Есть кусочки кода, которые возможно помогут разобраться в сути моего вопроса. Это сторона клиента:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::Send(TData* pData)
{
 if (!isConnected)
  return;
// #ifdef COM_LOG
// static int cnt = 0;
// Log << "MainForm->Send(" << ++cnt <<"): enter\n";
// #endif // COM_LOG
 AddTraffic(pData->Size);
 Sock->Send(pData);
}
```

Это запрос на регистрацию, но куда он его посылает, где сервер это примет, где обработает ответ от сервера не понятно:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Функция выполняет регистрацию (перерегистрацию) пользователя
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMainForm::Login()
{
 if (!isConnected)
  return;
 static bool bEnter = false; // Признак работы этой функции

 if (bEnter) // Вход недопустим, пока не закончится эта функция
  return;
 bEnter = true;
 try
 {
  #ifdef COM_LOG
  static int cnt = 0;
  if (CheckLog(lmLogin))
   Log << "Login(" << ++cnt <<"): enter" << endl;
  #endif // COM_LOG

  if (TLetter::IsLogged()) // Уже зарегистрирован?
  {
   #ifdef COM_LOG
   if (CheckLog(lmLogin))
    Log << "Login(" << cnt <<"): call Logout() for relogin" << endl;
   #endif // COM_LOG
   Logout(); // Перерегистрация


   return;
  }

  do
  {
   bReconnect = (TLetter::UserName != ""); // Признак автоматической
   // регистрации после автоматического установления соединения после
   // ошибочного разрыва соединения - без ввода имени и пароля
   //i250 if (!bReconnect) // Регистрация с запросом имени и пароля
   if(true) // i250 Регистрация с запросом имени и пароля
   {
    #ifdef COM_LOG
    if (CheckLog(lmLogin))
     Log << "Login(" << cnt <<"): show dialog" << endl;
    #endif // COM_LOG

                                bWhatSessionNow = bSSLSessionSetting ? stTryCreateSSL : stTCP;

                                if(!getLoginInfo(UserName, Password)) {
        bTryLogin = false;
        break;
        }

                                if(bWhatSessionNow == stTryCreateSSL)
                                 RequestCertificate(); //i293_1

   }
   ClientState = csLogin;
   TItemGroup::Init();
   LogText((AnsiString)"Login user " + UserName);
                        if(bWhatSessionNow != stTryCreateSSL) {
    TLetter Letter;
    Letter.ProcLoginNick(UserName);
                        }

  } while (false);

  #ifdef COM_LOG
  if (CheckLog(lmLogin))
   Log << "Login(" << cnt <<"): exit" << endl;
  #endif // COM_LOG
 }


 catch(...)
 {
  bEnter = false;
  throw;
 }
 bEnter = false;
}
```

Мне надо чтобы сервер принял запрос от постман и прислал какой-то ответ, чтобы я дальше разобрался и дописал уже свой микросервис

Comment: А протокол-то есть? Без протокола ничего не получится вообще. Если известно, что `под капотом используются сокеты`, то, скорее всего, используются чисто протоколы TCP или UDP. Тогда запросы `POST`, `GET`, `PUT` тут точно не сработают, это запросы протокола HTTP.

Comment: @maestro да. TCP протокол

Comment: Ну, `TCP` - и что? Поверх TCP что-то всё равно должно быть, это тоже называется протоколом, и оно должно быть описано в документации к серверу. Если этого нет, то вы ничего сделать не сможете. Как вы будете управлять подводной лодкой, если нигде не написано, какая кнопка за что отвечает, и вообще спрятана?